# Ways to simplify an if-statement in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8

I currently have an if-statement like this:

```
if (condition1 || condition2) {
     //Do stuff here
     //Small things happened here
     //More stuff

     if (condition1) {
          System.out.println("Thank");
          // Do Task Alpha
          // Do Task Beta
     } else {
          System.out.println("You");
          // Do Task Delta
          // Do Task Gamma
     }
}
```

So the basic idea is that the if statement happens when either of the conditions is true (In my case, both conditions cannot be true at the same time).

However, once inside the if statement, there is a point where if the first condition is true, print "Thank" and execute Task Alpha and Beta.  If the second condition is true, print "you" and execute Task Delta and Gamma.  A lot of common statements are executed before we reach this diverging point.

Is this the best/simplest way of writing this whole if statement?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you could simplify your code by using default values using `Optional.ofNullable` e.g. `String test = Optional.ofNullable(testStr).orElse("you");` might clean things up

Answer (score 8):

You could use a ternary for the inner if

```
String toPrint = test == null ? "Thank" : "You";
System.out.println(toPrint);
```

or even

```
System.out.println(test == null ? "Thank" : "You");
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way to write this operation, is exactly like you have in your question. If `condition1` is a complex, potentially expensive expression, store its result into a local `boolean` variable:

```
final boolean condition1Result = condition1;
if (condition1Result || condition2) {
     //Do stuff here
     //Small things happened here
     //More stuff

     if (condition1Result) {
          System.out.println("Thank");
          // Do Task Alpha
          // Do Task Beta
     } else {
          System.out.println("You");
          // Do Task Delta
          // Do Task Gamma
     }
}
```

It might be tempting to consider inlining common the code, i.e.

```
if(condition1) {
     //Do stuff here
     //Small things happened here
     //More stuff
     System.out.println("Thank");
     // Do Task Alpha
     // Do Task Beta
} else if(condition2) {
     //Do stuff here
     //Small things happened here
     //More stuff
     System.out.println("You");
     // Do Task Delta
     // Do Task Gamma
}
```

but I wouldn’t do it unless the common code is *really* tiny. The JVM should be capable of doing such optimization at runtime, if beneficial, so you should prefer the variant that avoids code duplication.

If the overall code becomes too complex, consider refactoring the blocks into methods.

Comment: I prefer extract a new method if I found I can use a meaniful name to introduce some common code even if it is really tiny.

Answer (score 0):

if the if-else blocks occur at the end of the wrapping `if` block - you can move them *after* the if block:

```
 if (test == null || testStr.equals("testStr")) {
 //Do stuff here
 //Small things happened here
 //More stuff
 }

 if (test == null) {
      System.out.println("Thank");
 } else if (testStr.equals("testStr")) {
      System.out.println("You");
 }
```

This way you have only one level of nesting.

Comment: Are you sure this equivalent? `test` may change inside the first `if`-body.

Comment: But you have to repeat the string comparison, and the program structure is less obvious.

Comment: @Andreas repeating a single string comparison is not very costly, and if it is (e.g. performed in a loop many times), we can do it once before the first if. As for the structure I humbly disagree with your statement, maybe it's a matter of opinion but from my experience I found that the less levels of nesting there are - the easier it is to follow the code.

Comment: @Socowi see my comment to Andreas, the same applies to the use-case you suggest, if the value of the `testStr` might change we can do the comparison once before the first if and save it into a boolean variable which will be used later on.

Comment: I'm afraid that the simplicity of baao's answer drove popularity, but what some of us forgot to take into account is that most chances are that it's just an example and the OP might want to do other things inside the if/else blocks, which means that the Conditional operator will not be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Chaining a lot of blocks makes the code more difficult to maintain.
One way to avoid these chained blocks is to use return more often to exit the method before reaching the lines of code that don't have to be executed after a condition is met. Check the refactored version of your example below:

```
private void someMethod(){
    /*If none of the conditions is met, exits without 
    executing any code.*/
    if (!(condition1 || condition2)) {
        return;
    }

    /*Executes code common to any of the two conditions.*/
    //Do stuff here
    //Small things happened here
    //More stuff

    if (condition1) {
        System.out.println("Thank");
        // Do Task Alpha
        // Do Task Beta
        /*After executing the code for the 1st condition,
        exit to avoid the code for the 2nd one to be executed.*/
        return;  
    } 

    /*If the execution reached up to here, then the 2nd
    condition was met and its corresponding code is executed.*/        
    System.out.println("You");
    // Do Task Delta
    // Do Task Gamma
}
```